# If isset statement not bringing up an input field

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

I have the following code where I am trying to get the 'Finalize Draft Order' submit button to only appear if the 'Create Draft Order' button has been pressed/set. Right now, the button does not show up after I hit the Create Draft Order button. It only displays if I take it out of the if(isset function.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<form method="POST" name="form">
<input type="submit" value="Create Draft Order" name="shuffle">
</form>

    Shuffled results: <br>
    <div class="main-bag">     
    <div class="shuffle_results" id="results"></div>
     <form method="post">
<?php
$count = 0;
    foreach ($array as $result) :
    $count++;
    $shuffle_count = $count;
        $shuffle_firstname = htmlentities($result['firstname']);
        $shuffle_lastname = htmlentities($result['lastname']);
        $shuffle_id = htmlentities($result['id']);
        $shuffle_username = htmlentities($result['username']);
        $shuffle_email = htmlentities($result['email']);
?>
    <input type="hidden" name="count[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_count; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="firstname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_firstname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="lastname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_lastname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_username; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="email[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_email; ?>">

<?php 

    endforeach;
    // only show this button if we have done a shuffle
     if ( isset($_POST['shuffle'] ) ) :
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Finalize Draft Order" name="insert">';
    endif;

?>
```

UPDATE:

```
$array = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
$array[] = array( 
'id' => $row['id'],
'firstname' => $row['firstname'], 
'lastname' => $row['lastname'], 
'username' => $row['username'], 
'email' => $row['email'] 
); 

if (isset($_POST['shuffle'])) {

   }
}
shuffle($array);
    echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: You're not actually posting shuffle as a var. add it to your input hiddens rather than the name of the button

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Your input submit button is named "shuffle" but your posted data does not include "shuffle" as a post variable/argument.

Comment: it's a scope issue and a missing closing `</form>` tag for your second form.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'd assumed that was cut off.

Comment: Yes, it was cut off to minimize the amount of code I put in here.

Comment: Why can't a input button from a form be set?

Comment: firstly, we don't know where/how `$array` is assigned and pulling what. Then you're trying to pull POST info from your 2nd form, and relying on the first to do so; least, that's what I get from what you posted.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: I have error checking on and it does not report anything that has to do with this.

Comment: Funny, that's not what you said [here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339811/if-isset-statement-not-bringing-up-an-input-field#comment52554821_32339886) or is that irrelevant?

Comment: I forgot to mention that?? Not everyone is perfect and knows ALL

Comment: I calls 'em as I sees 'em.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think $_POST['shuffle'] is set. instead of using the submit button for it change your code to:

```
<form method="POST" name="form">
<input type="hidden" name="shuffle" value="true">
<input type="submit" value="Create Draft Order">
</form>
```

I'm pretty sure submit's name doesn't count for the POST values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's you're issue. Your input button is named shuffle, which is not passed when submitting. If you add a new hidden input element with the name "shuffle" that will pass it through.

**edit:**

You've said in your question its after the create draft button is pressed. Therefore as per your example:

```
<form method="POST" name="form">
<input type="submit" value="Create Draft Order" name="form">
<input type="hidden" name="shuffle" value="1">
</form>

    Shuffled results: <br>
    <div class="main-bag">     
    <div class="shuffle_results" id="results"></div>
     <form method="post">
<?php
$count = 0;
    foreach ($array as $result) :
    $count++;
    $shuffle_count = $count;
        $shuffle_firstname = htmlentities($result['firstname']);
        $shuffle_lastname = htmlentities($result['lastname']);
        $shuffle_id = htmlentities($result['id']);
        $shuffle_username = htmlentities($result['username']);
        $shuffle_email = htmlentities($result['email']);
?>
    <input type="hidden" name="count[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_count; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="firstname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_firstname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="lastname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_lastname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_username; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="email[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_email; ?>">

<?php 

    endforeach;
    // only show this button if we have done a shuffle
     if ( isset($_POST['shuffle'] ) ) :
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Finalize Draft Order" name="insert">';
endif;
?>
```

Comment: I tried doing this except I changed the name to shuffleButton and then changed `$_POST['shuffleButton']` and I did not get it to show up either.

Comment: You're not listening to what I'm saying. Look at my code. There's an input field with the name which matches your isset check

Comment: Look at this line: <input type="hidden" name="shuffle" value="1">

Comment: I understand. I did that except I did this..`<input type="hidden" name="shuffleButton" value="1">` and then this.. `$_POST['shuffleButton']` ... I have things in my code that work off of the name `name="shuffle"`, so I did not want to disturb all of that.

Comment: Try dumping `$_POST` by doing a `var_dump($_POST)` and see what the deal is

Comment: Does it matter where I put the var_dump?

Comment: Don't put it in a loop, put it at the top of the file.

Comment: I get this..array(0) { }

Comment: And what happens when you post the form?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: shuffleButton in /home4/dfgdgdg/public_html/example.com/admin_dashboard.php on line 460
NULL

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what to try to debug. I posted another part of code that I have that the form sends to via AJAX to get the results. That is where my array comes from. I have the if (isset code in there, but it does nothing before I changed any of this.

Comment: ... I moved the input from the second form to the first. Sorry but that's just lazy. You can easily see the difference between your code and mine or use the view edits button on stack overflow

Comment: I didn't see it and have no idea what view edits button you are referring to. I tried that and it did not help.

Comment: @Becky how did it not help?

Comment: the button still doesn't show after I click the Create Draft Order button.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of PHP meame69 and ScottyMcGready are using, but you very much CAN check to see if the button was clicked by checking for the isset($_POST["submit"]) is true.

http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-check-if-the-submit-button-is-clicked-in-PHP.php

I cannot comment yet, but I will edit this once I figure out what's wrong with Becky's code.

Comment: The button is being pressed because everything else that button does works. Just not this if statement.

Comment: I'm running your code on an online php compiler and the button shows up when it's being pressed.

Try doing a print_r($_POST) in your code and let me know what that gives you.

Comment: Then the issue is you're not getting any posting to that page at all.

Comment: I am though. Because the script I put on here works in terms of what it is actually doing. Plus I have a thousand other lines of codes with multiple POST's that work.

Comment: Encapsulate your second form in the if(isset($_POST['submit']). Do you still have your hidden stuff running? The answer will be No because the form you have isn't posting to itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88513/discussion-between-j-han-and-becky).